# About an integration technique

Tags: calculus

My professor wrote this :

$\displaystyle \int  x^2\log(\sqrt{1-x^2}) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{3}\int \log(\sqrt{1-x^2})   \, \mathrm dx^3$

Can someone explain me what is going on with the integration variable ?

Comment: Change of variables?

Comment: What's the changed variable here ?

Comment: $3x^2\,dx = dx^3$ since $\frac{d}{dx}x^3 = \frac{dx^3}{dx}=3x^2$.

Comment: Thank you ! The notation he used is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

$$\int x^2 \log\sqrt{1-x^2} dx = \int x^2 \log\sqrt{1-(x^3)^{2/3}} dx$$
Let $u = x^3$, so $du = 3x^2 dx$ or 
$$dx = \frac{du}{3x^2}$$
so the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{x^2}{3x^2} \log\sqrt{1-u^{2/3}} du = \frac{1}{3} \int \log\sqrt{1-u^{2/3}} du \ .$$
Resubstituting $u = x^3$ yields the rather confusing expression of your professor.

Answer (score 0):

$
\int x^2 \log \sqrt{1 - x^2} \ dx \\
= \int x^2 \log \sqrt{1 - x^2} \ \frac{dx}{dx^3} \ dx^3 \\
= \int x^2 \log \sqrt{1 - x^2} \ \frac{1}{3x^2} \ dx^3 \\
= \frac13 \int \log \sqrt{1 - x^2} \ dx^3
$